# KnockoutJS: based on length of array enable button

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, knockout.js, enable-if

In a project we're doing, we have created an inbox where the users (amongst other things) can select the items. If a user selects an item, the button should be enabled -- if none are selected, the button should be disabled.

Simple enough, but for the life of me, I can't get it working :-(

You can find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rzrfp/

I presume I'm missing something very, very, VERY simple and stupid, but I've been tried virtually everything, and can't get it working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ko.computed` instead of `ko.computable`.
Or even better: use `data-bind="enable: selectedItems().length > 0"` in your button element.
So you can omit the computed `showButton`.

EDIT: To use the right context use `var modelImpl = new myModel("myParam");`. Otherwise `this` inside the model refers to the `window` object.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that ... Guess looking too long at the screen does make you blind ... ;-)

Comment: `enable` not `enabled`